# Change text in DIV onchange

Tags: html, text, onchange

I have some variables stored in Javacript like this:

```
 var prices = {
 'product1' = '3,99',
 'product2' = '5,99' };
```

I have a select element which looks like this:

```
 <select name="product">
 <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
 <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
 </select>
```

And I have a DIV, which looks like this:

```
 <div id="price"></div>
```

What I want to do is that when you choose a product in the select element, the price is being loaded from the var prices into the DIV. Is there a way to do this with using onchange or do I need to use an other method?

I already tried to update the data of a variable like this:

```
 var prices = name[price];
     function updatevariable(data) { 
         value = data;
         alert(value);
     } 

  <select onchange="document.getElementById('size').onchange = function() {
                         var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
                         showSize(value);>
```

Comment: I added the code I tried to my post.

Comment: The onChange event of your select element is setting the onChange event of #size? What element is #size? And where did `name` come from? Are you actually using `updatevariable` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8TYt7/)

**HTML:**  (Note: I added an ID to your select

```
<select id="product" name="product">
    <option value="product0">Choose one</option>
    <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
</select>
<div id="price"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var item, pr;
var prices = {
    'product1' : '3,99',
    'product2' : '5,99' 
};

$('#product').change(function() {
    item = $(this).val();
    pr = prices[item];
    $('#price').html(pr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<select onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = this.value" name="product">
```